# OCaml - print before returning from a function

Tags: printing, functional-programming, range, ocaml

I've got a function in OCaml that returns the range from two numbers (taken from https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html):

```ml
let rec range a b =
  if a > b then []
  else a :: range (a + 1) b;;
```

This function makes sense but I'd like to be actually print out the range.

My first instinct was to try something like this:

```ml
let rec range a b =
  if a > b then []
  else print_int a; a :: range (a + 1) b;;
```

but this threw the error: `Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type 'a list`
which makes sense because I'm now essentially returning a unit value, since OCaml is interpreting the print statement as something it should *return*.

So, is there some best practice here that would allow me to *print* the value and then *return* what I'd like to? Pretty new to functional programming so forgive the simple question.

Comment: Use the parentheses, Luke! `(print_int a; a :: range (a + 1) b)`

Comment: oh awesome thanks, this worked! In a situation like this, does OCaml just return the last value specified in the parens? So it prints out a first, and then returns range (a + 1) b?

Comment: `;` does. it's a sequence operator, not a statement terminator. `;` will evaluate but ignore the expression that come before it, and return the value of the expressions that comes after. The problem here is that without parentheses the "before" expression is the entire if expression. Adding parentheses makes that a sub-expression of the `else` branch instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @glennl said in the comment it's just a parenthesis problem.
Just note that you can also use a `begin` `end` structure instead of parenthesis if you find it more clear (but it's just a matter of style) :

```ml
let rec range a b =
  if a > b then []
  else begin
      print_int a; 
      a :: range (a + 1) b
  end;;
```